# Error String Index out of range java

Tags: java, string

Buenas tengo una clase Persona, donde creo un objeto y lo almaceno en la lista. En el menu me funcionan todas las opciones menos la de borrar un objeto Persona de la lista. Os dejo el codigo de la funcion main de la opcion de borrar elementos de una lista:

```
case 2://Borrar persona de la lista, la búsqueda se hace por dni
 if(lista.isEmpty()){ //Lista vacía, no se puede borrar nada
  System.out.println("Lista vacia");
  break;
 }
 else{ //Si se puede borrar personas de la lista
  System.out.println("Introduce el dni de la persona");
  String dniBorrar=s.nextLine();
  Persona a=new Persona(dniBorrar);
  if(erasePersona(a)){
   System.out.println("Persona correctamente eliminada de la lista");
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("Persona no encontrada en la lista");
  }
 }
 break;
```

Aqui os dejo el codigo de la funcion que borrar una persona pasada por parametro de la lista.

```
static boolean erasePersona(Persona aux){
       for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            if(aux.getDni().equals(lista.get(i).getDni())){
                lista.remove(aux);
                //Persona correctamente eliminada
                return true;
            }
       } 
       //Persona no encontrada en la lista
       return false;
    }
```

Y aqui os dejo el codigo que valida un dni pasado por parametro.

```
public boolean validarDni(String dni){
            // Array con las letras posibles del dni en su posición
            char[] letraDni = {
                'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D',  'X',  'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'
            };  
            String num= "";
            int resto = 0;  
            // compruebo que el 9º digito es una letra
            if (!Character.isLetter(dni.charAt(8))) {
                 return false;  
            }
            // compruebo su longitud que sea 9
            if (dni.length() != 9){   
                 return false;
            }  
            // Compruebo que lo 8 primeros digitos son numeros
            for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                 if(!Character.isDigit(dni.charAt(i))){
                       return false;    
                 }
                 // si es numero, lo recojo en un String
                 num += dni.charAt(i);     
            }
            // Paso String a entero los numeros del dni
            resto = Integer.parseInt(num);
            // Calculo la letra que le corresponde al dni
            resto %= 23;
            // verifico que la letra del dni corresponde con la del array
            if ((Character.toUpperCase(dni.charAt(8))) != letraDni[resto]){
                 return false;
           }  
           //DNI CORRECTO
           return true;
    }
```

La cosa es que el error por pantalla es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu objeto `dni`  no tiene un índice   `8`, eso es lo que dice el error. Deberías imponer en tu código una restricción para no permitir que el valor para el DNI sea aceptado si no tiene `N` cantidad de caracteres y aún así, para que el código no se rompa quizá meter la validación dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`  para controlar las posibles excepciones, creando un código robusto.

Comment: Por ejemplo, una forma de atar corto al usuario, haciendo que escriba exactamente `8` caracteres sería: `String dniBorrar=""; while((dniBorrar=s.nextLine()).length()!=8) { System.out.print("Tu entrada no es válida. Introduce 8 caracteres para el DNI: "); }` Haciendo eso el código no seguirá funcionando a lo loco, creyendo que todo es color de rosa (programación optimista yo le llamo, pero que lleva al fracaso), hasta que el usuario no cumpla esa restricción. Y el programa queda optimizado, porque no pasará a otras etapas para luego saltar con un error o una validación abocada al fracaso.

Comment: He mirado si es problema del dni de que tenga longitud 8, pero no es asi, porque si el dni no tiene esa longitud me genera un dni aleatorio, entonces no es ese problema.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *String index out of range*. Significa que estás buscando en la cadena un índice que no existe, sea `8` o el que sea. Puse lo del `8` como un ejemplo, porque esa es la cantidad que muestra tu captura de pantalla.

Comment: [Aquí está el problema que ocurre en tu código](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-charat-method-example/), de acuerdo al mensaje de error que muestras. Observa la parte en la que se intenta acceder mediante `charAt()` a un índice que no existe en la cadena.

Comment: Pero no entiendo, si inserto un dni y esta mal, el programa me genera un dni validado aleatorio, por tanto tiene la posicion 8 en la cadena y podria acceder a ella. Es decir, si introduzco de dni ejemplo34, luego me genera un dni aleatorio validado y me lo asigna. Por tanto no entiendo bien el error.

Comment: En el código no veo donde se genera ese DNI aleatorio del que hablas. ¿Puedes indicar dónde ocurre eso?

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de toda la clase Persona?

Comment: Acabo de agregar todo el codigo, es un poco largo, pero es muy simple todos los metodos, ejecutenlo y lo unico que da error es la opcion 2 y veran el error que me muestra por pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Codigo completo Clase Persona:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Persona{
    private String dni_,nombre_,apellidos_,direccion_,localidad_;
    private int edad_;
    static final double MAX=99999999;
    static final String v="VACIO";
    static ArrayList<Persona> lista=new ArrayList<Persona>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion=0;
        do{
            menu();
            opcion=s.nextInt();
            switch(opcion){
                case 1://Crear una persona y añadirla a la lista
                    newPersona();
                    break;
                case 2://Borrar persona de la lista, la búsqueda se hace por dni
                    if(lista.isEmpty()){ //Lista vacía, no se puede borrar nada
                        System.out.println("Lista vacia");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{ //Si se puede borrar personas de la lista
                        System.out.println("Introduce el dni de la persona");
                        String dniBorrar=s.nextLine();
                        Persona a=new Persona(dniBorrar);
                        if(!validarDni(a.getDni())){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if(erasePersona(a)){
                            System.out.println("Persona correctamente eliminada de la lista");
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Persona no encontrada en la lista");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: //Mostrar todas las personas en la lista
                    if(lista.isEmpty()){//Lista vacía, no se puede mostrar nada
                        System.out.println("Lista vacia");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{ //Muestra por pantalla todas las personas
                        printPersonas();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("En la lista hay "+lista.size()+" elementos");
                    break;
                case 5: //Salir del programa
                    System.out.println("Hasta pronto!");
                    break;
                default: //Control de errores
                    System.out.println("Error en la opcion insertada");
                    break;
            }
        }while(opcion!=5);
    }
    /**
     * Menu opciones de la clase Persona
     */
    static void menu(){
        System.out.println("                --MENU DE OPCIONES-- ");
        System.out.println("1.Meter persona en la lista");
        System.out.println("2.Borrar persona de la lista");
        System.out.println("3.Mostrar todas las personas de la lista");
        System.out.println("4.Numero de personas en la lista");
        System.out.println("5.Salir");
    }
    /**
     * Constructor Persona que se le pasan todos los parametros
     * @param dni
     * @param nombre
     * @param apellidos
     * @param edad
     * @param direccion
     * @param localidad
     * @return void
     */
    Persona(String dni,String nombre,String apellidos,int edad,String direccion,String localidad){ 
        if(!setDni(dni)){
            System.out.println("DNI INCORRECTO");
            //GENERA DNI ALEATORIO
            dni=dniAleatorio();
        }
        if(nombre.isEmpty()){
            nombre_=v;
        }
        if(apellidos.isEmpty()){
            apellidos_=v;
        }
        if(edad<0){
            edad_=18;
        }
        if(direccion.isEmpty()){
            direccion_=v;
        }
        if(localidad.isEmpty()){
            localidad_="CORDOBA";
        }
        dni_=dni;
        nombre_=nombre;
        apellidos_=apellidos;
        edad_=edad;
        direccion_=direccion;
        localidad_=localidad;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor Persona que solo le pasa el dni, los demás parametros 
     * se rellenan por defecto
     * @param dni
     */
    Persona(String dni){
        if(!setDni(dni)){
            System.out.println("DNI INCORRECTO");
            //GENERA DNI ALEATORIO
            dni=dniAleatorio();
        }
        dni_=dni;
        nombre_=v;
        apellidos_=v;
        edad_=18;
        direccion_=v;
        localidad_="CORDOBA";
    }
    //GETTERS
    public String getDni(){return dni_;}
    public String getNombre(){return nombre_;}
    public String getApellidos(){return apellidos_;}
    public int getEdad(){return edad_;}
    public String getDireccion(){return direccion_;}
    public String getLocalidad(){return localidad_;}

    //SETTERS
    public boolean setNombre(String nombre){
        if(nombre.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        nombre_=nombre;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setApellidos(String apellidos){
        if(apellidos.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        apellidos_=apellidos;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setEdad(int edad){
        if(edad<0){
            return false;
        }
        edad_=edad;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setDireccion(String direccion){
        if(direccion.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        direccion_=direccion;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setLocalidad(String localidad){
        if(localidad.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        localidad_=localidad;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setDni(String dni){
        if(!validarDni(dni)){
            return false;
        }
        dni_=dni;
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Funcion que devuelve true si el dni pasado por parametro es correcto
     * o false si no lo es
     * @param dni
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static boolean validarDni(String dni){
            // Array con las letras posibles del dni en su posición
            char[] letraDni = {
                'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D',  'X',  'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'
            };  
            String num= "";
            int resto = 0;  
            // compruebo que el 9º digito es una letra
            if (!Character.isLetter(dni.charAt(8))) {
                 return false;  
            }
            // compruebo su longitud que sea 9
            if (dni.length() != 9){   
                 return false;
            }  
            // Compruebo que lo 8 primeros digitos son numeros
            for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
                 if(!Character.isDigit(dni.charAt(i))){
                       return false;    
                 }
                 // si es numero, lo recojo en un String
                 num += dni.charAt(i);     
            }
            // Paso String a entero los numeros del dni
            resto = Integer.parseInt(num);
            // Calculo la letra que le corresponde al dni
            resto %= 23;
            // verifico que la letra del dni corresponde con la del array
            if ((Character.toUpperCase(dni.charAt(8))) != letraDni[resto]){
                 return false;
           }  
           //DNI CORRECTO
           return true;
    }
    /**
     * Genera un dni aleatorio
     * @return String 
     */
    public static String dniAleatorio(){
        //Genera numero aleatorio 
        System.out.println("GENERANDO DNI ALEATORIO...");
        String dni;
        int num=(int)(Math.random()*MAX);
        String numDni=Integer.toString(num);
        int resto=num%23;
        //Calcula la letra del dni que le corresponde a ese numero
        String []letras={"T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E"};
        String letraDni=letras[resto];
        //Concatena todo y devuelve el string
        dni=numDni+letraDni;
        return dni;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Mi nombre es "+this.getNombre()+" "+this.getApellidos()+", mi edad es "+this.getEdad()+" con dni "+this.getDni()+" y vivo en la localidad "+this.getLocalidad()+" en la calle "+this.getDireccion()+"\n");
    }
    /**
     * Crea una persona y la devuelve con los datos insertados
     */
    static void newPersona(){
        System.out.println("Inserta los datos del usuario: dni | nombre | apellidos | edad | direccion | localidad: ");
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        String dni;
            do{
                System.out.println("DNI : ");
                dni=s.nextLine();
                if(dni.length()!=9){
                    System.out.println("LONGITUD ERRONEA DEL DNI, VUELVE A INTRODUCIRLA");
                }
            }while(dni.length()!=9); 
        System.out.println("NOMBRE : ");
        String nombre=s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("APELLIDOS : ");
        String apellidos=s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("EDAD : ");
        int edad=s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("DIRECCION : ");
        String direccion=s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("LOCALIDAD : ");
        String localidad=s.nextLine();
        Persona aux=new Persona(dni,nombre,apellidos,edad,direccion,localidad);
        addPersonaToList(aux);
    }
    /**
     * Añade una persona a la lista
     * @param aux
     */
    static void addPersonaToList(Persona aux){
        lista.add(aux);
        System.out.println("Persona correctamente escrita en la lista");
    }
    /**
     * Borra un elemento Persona de la lista
     * @param Persona aux
     */
    static boolean erasePersona(Persona aux){
       for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            if(aux.getDni().equals(lista.get(i).getDni())){
                lista.remove(aux);
                //Persona correctamente eliminada
                return true;
            }
       } 
       //Persona no encontrada en la lista
       return false;
    }
    /**
     * Me muestra por pantalla todos las Personas guardadas en la lista
     */
    static void printPersonas(){
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
            System.out.println(lista.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor no añadas tu código como una respuesta, simplemente edita tu pregunta y lo añades.